# UIPageViewController subviews move behind the status bar after screen tap

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

So, I have a segue from UICollecionView item tapped to UIPageViewController. When PageViewController shows, the navigation bar makes dark gray, and UIView in it has a strange offset.
However, after i click once in any place on screen, I see a strange "animation" and UIView moves up into its correct place. 
So, all views on screen get moved.

Here is the link for 5-second video with this bug: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNbwBGvSzIk

PageViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = [[[EVAEvent events] objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex] name];
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc, nil];
    [self setViewControllers:controllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{
//    NSLog(@"View Controller At Index = %lu", (unsigned long)self.currentIndex);
    EVAEventInfoViewController *controller = [EVAEventInfoViewController getFromStoryboard];
    EVAEvent *event = [[EVAEvent events] objectAtIndex:index];
    [controller setIndex:index];
    [controller setEvent:event];
    return controller;
}
```

EVAEventInfoViewController.m:

```
+ (EVAEventInfoViewController *) getFromStoryboard
{
    //NSLog(@"Creating EVAEventInfoViewController");
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    EVAEventInfoViewController *this = (EVAEventInfoViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventInfoController"];
    return this;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25):

try adding

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

in PageViewController's viewDidLoad

Comment: worked for me on Swift iOS 8.1. using this code `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=false`

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3: what worked for me was setting "Adjust Scroll View Insets" to false from the storyboard. Your tip helped, though.

Answer (score 1):

I set UIPageViewController and sub view controller with
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;` but it does not work if **UITabBarController** as root.

I captured the view hierarchy as the following [image]
[image]

You can see the UIPageViewControllerContentView are correct position (0,0). But
UIView under _UIQueuingScrollView generated the offset of status bar.

So, I decided not to use UIPageViewController. I use self.view addSubView to fixed this issue.

```
- (void)loadVC:(UIViewController*)vc
{
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}
```